# есть ли максимальный размер у массивов в java?

Tags: java, массивы, jvm

Есть массив byte[]. Чем ограничивается его максимальный размер?
Влияет ли на это размер стека Xss для JVM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Массивы хранятся в куче. Размер массива ограничивается памятью, выделенной для JVM. Но не только.

Если я не ошибаюсь, то при достаточном размере выделенной памяти, в массив можно записать `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8` элементов. И это не зависит от типа массива. 8 байт резервируются для информации об объекте (mark word).

Также, если найденная мной информация правильно понята, то есть еще зависимости от платформы. Но в найденных источниках нет цифры меньше `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8`.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/31388054/3978990
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/35756668/3978990
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/8381338/3978990

Comment: В HotSpot JVM максимальный размер (любого) массива `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2` (не - 8), и с mark word это не связано.